# disadvantages of binding to ANY interface

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, bind

I have a server that binds to a specific IP address (In a linux system). We are considering the option to bind(0), ie to bind to ANY interface. Are there any problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. You may

- want to have different processes binding to different IPs. In this
  case you don't want any to bind to all.
- want the server to be
  accessible only from internal network (for instance, when the other
  interface is accessible from the outer world).
- want something that I can't think of at the moment.

basically, it's not the binding that has disadvantages, but the effect thereof and it all depends if this is what you want.

Comment: Additionally, depending on how much access you have to the incoming data, you *might* not be able to discern what interface things actually arrived in

Comment: Also, you can't send UDP broadcasts if bound to ANY.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, it is excellent practice to only bind to the addresses/interfaces you need to: a firewall on the local machine may not always be there to prevent access from unauthorized sources.

Comment: Let's say that I have eth0:1.2.3.4 and eth1:5.6.7.8 but I bind to 0.0.0.0:80. How does an external client access my server? I guess that connection to 1.2.3.4:80 or 5.6.7.8:80 will fail, therefore I need to route the packets to ANY?

Comment: @fge, +1, the firewall is a workaround, anyway, if you don't need the service, why run it on the interface in the first place ;-)

Comment: No, the client accesses your server using err... ANY ip address that is accessible to it.

Comment: @cateof: `0.0.0.0` does mean any. That is, IPv4 any. So, connection will succeed. You may also see `::`, which means the server will answer any connection on both IPv4 and IPv6, at least on Linux -- I believe OpenBSD behaves differently there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You may want to listen to `ANY` if you *don't know* what your IP address is or will be.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, I personally don't see the firewall as a workaround, in fact I have one on each and every server, this way I am sure not to let anything slip through ;)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker in case we finally listen to ANY, can we always identify the client's IP? No?

Comment: "want the server to be accessible only from internal network" binding to the internal interface does *not* accomplish that. An attacker behind the external interface may be able to reach a service bound to the IP address of the internal interface if he knows the internal IP address. Note that disabling ip_forward has no effect on this, since a packet from one interface reaching a service bound to the address of another is *not* considered forwarding. To secure the service, firewall rules should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious issue would be that if you depend on network topology to provide access control and safety (firewalls etc) then the presence of multiple interfaces might mean that not all access to the server is being protected at the same degree. This could especially be a problem if interfaces are added or changed in the future.

Also, if your server has a notion of "its own IP" for its own purposes and it is not programmed for the eventuality that different client connections will be established to different "local" IPs then that might present a problem -- of course, you 'd need to read the source to weigh in on this.